# ModuleNotFound Error on Flask app where modules on same dir

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Here is my current directory stucture

[image]

My FLASK_APP environment variable is set to app.py

and on that app.py I have this import variables

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify

from dataproviders import provider
from usecase import useCases
```

However, upon running the flask run I always end up getting this error.

```
  File "C:\Users\USER\projects\project\lambda\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from dataproviders import provider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataproviders'
```

The issue can be fixed by doing

```
from .dataproviders import provider
from .usecase import useCases
```

But is there anyway for us to import it  using

```
from dataproviders import provider
from usecase import useCases
```

Without encountering any error like ModuleNotFoundError?

Comment: How about adding it to `sys.path`?

Comment: @codekaizer can you provide an example on how it is done with sys.path?

Comment: @codekaizer I believe that's correct solution as well